# Profiling .NET Standard DLL in VS2019

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, profiling, visual-studio-2019, .net-standard

I am using VS2019 Professional to develop a Xamarin.Forms app.  The project solution consists of the typical head projects which deploy to specific platforms, and the common cross-platform project that contains the bulk of the solution's code.  I am trying to find some way, if possible, to run performance tests on the common cross-platform project, which builds to a .NET Standard DLL.

Xamarin currently does not have any tooling available to profile the platform-specific app using the DLL, so I need to find some other way.  I have unit tests for this DLL, but there doesn't seem to be any support for profiling unit tests in VS2019.  I have tried profiling the vstest.console application that runs the unit tests that test my DLL, but the only option available is to instrument vstest.console, which will do me no good either (obviously don't want to go mucking around with the guts of the test runner!).  At this point it seems the only option is to develop an additional test console application and profile that, but I just wanted to check if anyone has encountered a similar use case and found a more elegant solution?

Comment: Memory/CPU usage? The time some operations take? The thing about a netstandard library is that its execution depends on the platform so you can have different results whether it runs on a netcore unit test runner (windows, Linux, Mac) or other like Android. We have a Xamarin.Forms project with netstandard librairies, we have unit tests running on netcore (for the CI and local) and we are setting up an Android emulator that will host a xUnit runner to launch the tests on it. We have several differences running the app on netcore and Android. Back to your question you can try BenchmarkDotNet

Comment: At this point I am just trying to get any kind of profiling in general to work.  I suppose if I had to peg a particular to profile it would probably be some metric of how many times a function is run in a test benched operation, so I could have some idea of the "hot" parts of code to focus on optimizing.

Comment: @polkduran I hadn't considered xUnit, never messed with it before.  Is what you're doing a fairly standard operation?  Could you refer me to any relevant documentation you're using?